# Using emscripten to compile c++ code to javascript for making the sum of two numbers.Practice

Tags: javascript, html, c++, emscripten

I want to make a short example to understand how **emscripten** works.
I want to make a **html** where I could add two numbers in two different text box. I also added a button and a third text box where the result should be printed after I introduce two numbers above and I pressed the button.

Comment: Does Emscripten require `main`?

Comment: Yes, it requires.

Comment: Did You try this tutorial? (https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/Tutorial.html)

Comment: With this tutorial i get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few issues with your project. First, I think you should tag the C++ functions with `EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE` like this:

```
int EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE int_sum_of_two_numbers(int number1, int number2)
{
    int sum;
    sum = number1 + number2;
    return sum; 
}
```

From the [Emscripten documentation](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#why-do-functions-in-my-c-c-source-code-vanish-when-i-compile-to-javascript-and-or-i-get-no-functions-to-process):

> If your function is used in other functions, LLVM may inline it and it will not appear as a unique function in the JavaScript. Prevent inlining by defining the function with EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE

That allows Javascript code to find your C++ functions.

Besides that, the command you use to compile your project seems to have an extra underscore `_` character when you mention the exported functions `_int_sum_of_two_numbers` => `int_sum_of_two_numbers`. So you should have used:

```
EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='["int_sum_of_two_numbers"]'
```

As a final note, you could leave the `main()` function empty. The code inside that function is irrelevant to your web application.

I wrote an article a while ago about [integrating WebAssembly with Angular](https://componenthouse.com/2018/02/15/how-to-make-angular-and-webassembly-work-together/) and it is very similar to what you are trying to achieve. I think this would be worth reading.

Comment: If you still have issues, then maybe you should add more information about your HTML page. I don't see any reference to the generated `wasm` file in that code.